# %p formats to 8 hex digits for a 64-bit binary

Tags: c, gcc

I have a 64-bit binary (modfied version of sqlite, but this shouldn't mattrr):

```
> file /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/sqlite/sqlite3
/home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/sqlite/sqlite3: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x39a2db352d3bc451ed621ad0588eec3008df034b, not stripped
```

produced with GCC 4.7.4. However, debugging code in it outputs just 8 hex digits (32 bits) for `%p` in format string, where I expected 16. Is this normal?

Comment: Could you show the output ?

Comment: There is no output and no code producint any output in your question. Without both it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the C standard where a specific formatting is required. Hint: the documentations of `printf` will already answer your question. Please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on linux/glibc, the `%p`format specifier does not do left padding with zeroes. Thus a pointer to e.g. address 0x000000000000ffff is formatted simply as "0xffff". You can use `%.16p` if you want 16 digits in the output.

Comment: AFAIK `"%.16p"` is gnu specific.

Comment: Looking at the POSIX specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), there is nothing in the wording about the `p` conversion specification to indicate that the flags, width and precision are not allowed, though since the format it implementation-defined, the effect of those modifiers is likewise unclear.